# Nested DIVs, how to make children truly inside?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make nested divs, so I can position children with top and left, so they can overlap each other:

https://jsfiddle.net/e0cpuarv/

```css
      .boo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      
      .kah1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 30px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
      }
      
      .kah2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        top: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
  <body>

    <div class="boo">
      <div class="kah1"></div>
      <div class="kah2"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

It works with one huge drawback - children just are on the top of parent. What should I do to make them be inside parent, like this?

[desiredresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY9Px.png)

In fact, children may be not DIVs, IMGs will be enough too, if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
 body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}   
     .boo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: red;
      }

      .kah1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 30px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .kah2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        top: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/e0cpuarv/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this did the job! =)

Comment: Why sir @VictorMuller

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.boo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: red;
      }
```

to this:

```
.boo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: red;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7nvwogdx/)

Basically you add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element `.boo` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the overwflow with `overflow: hidden`, so in your case the css would be like this:

```css
      .boo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: red;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      
      .kah1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 30px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
      }
      
      .kah2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        top: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
  <body>

    <div class="boo">
      <div class="kah1"></div>
      <div class="kah2"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just make the main div (.boo) position: relative

see the code, and change the left and top values for kah1 and kah2 to position the inner boxes

```css
      .boo {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: red;
      }
      
      .kah1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 12px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
      }
      
      .kah2 {
        position: absolute;
        right: 25px;
        top: 12px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
  <body>

    <div class="boo">
      <div class="kah1"></div>
      <div class="kah2"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
```